# custom title android onClick , wrong id called

Tags: android, onclick, title

I have implemented a custom title to my activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#3a5894" >

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="50dp"
       android:layout_height="100dp"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:id="@+id/left_button_title_bar_main_content_fragment"
       android:background="#90C3D4"
       android:onClick="onClickTitleBar">

       <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:background="#90C3D4"/>

   </LinearLayout>


   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:id="@+id/center_textview_title_bar" 
       android:onClick="onClickTitleBar">

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:paddingTop="15dp"
           android:text="Quick Notes"
           android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My activity implementation :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {



    private LinearLayout leftButtonInTitle;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // custom title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

        // full screen activity
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        // custom title bar
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title_bar);


        leftButtonInTitle = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_button_title_bar_main_content_fragment);
```

and the method where I would like to handle click

```
public void onClickTitleBar(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();

        Log.e("","id :  "+id);
        Log.e("","button id:  " + R.id.left_button_title_bar_main_content_fragment);
}
```

and I have logged out the v.getId and the linearlayout actual id. 
And I have realized the ids are not the same.

here is the log :

```
E/﹕ id   2131493001
E/﹕ button id:  2131493000
```

As you can see the numbers are not the same.

Any idea why this is happening ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the onClick on the LinearLayout with the ID `R.id.center_textview_title_bar` as well. Because it is in a RelativeLayout, and no constraints are set, and it is "higher up" in the order of the children, it will be displayed on top of the LinearLayout with the ID `R.id.left_button_title_bar_main_content_fragment` and it will pick up all clicks in place of the title bar.

To fix this, remove the line

```
android:onClick="onClickTitleBar"
```

From the LinearLayout with the ID `R.id.center_textview_title_bar`

Answer (score 0):

In your `xml` file, value of `onClick` attribute of both LinearLayout is same.
May be you are getting different IDs because of that.

Try giving different values of `onClick` for both LinearLayouts.